# Python Get Multiple Random Lines From File

Tags: python, random

Can some one help me with this real quick? Here is my code I am using:

```
# Lists:
anchorslist = []

#Files:
anchors = open(basepath + "anchors.txt", "r")

#Placed In List:
for line in anchors:
        anchorslist.append(line.replace("\n", "|"))

#Used:
type(anchorslist)
```

It will return a random line from my text file. What I want to achieve is getting let's say 10 random lines returned like this:

```
random_anchor1|random_anchor2|random_anchor3|random_anchor4
```

I'm using this for the random.

```
def type(name):
    value = name[random.randint(0,len(name)-1)]
    return value
```

How would I modify the code to return that? Thanks.

Comment: Why will your current code returns a random line? Where do you make it random or return a line at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want to use is the `random` python module. With that, you can use `random.choice(anchorlist)` to select a random line from the list. Here is some code that would achieve that:

```
import random
# Lists:
anchorslist = []

#Files:
anchors = open("anchors.txt", "r")

#Placed In List:
for line in anchors:
        anchorslist.append(line.replace("\n", "|"))

anchors.close()

rand_options = anchorslist  # duplicate list, better than editting the input list
rand_vals = []
length = 3  # configure to 10, or how ever many random lines you want

for _ in range(length):
    rand_val = random.choice(rand_options)
    rand_vals.append(rand_val)    
    rand_options.remove(rand_val)  # remove from list so you don't get duplicates (unless you don't mind those)

what_you_want = "".join(rand_vals).rstrip("|")
```

Say anchors.txt = "Hello \n I \n am \n some \n random \n stuff",
    what_you_want = "I|stuff|Hello"

Answer (score 3):

```
 '|'.join(random.sample(anchorlist,10))
```

`random.sample(anchorlist,10)`  return 10 random elements from anchorlist

`'|'.join(...)` concatenate the list using `|` as separator